# Reference connection string in EF code first migration code

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I want to use the current connection string that was supplied to Update-Database via the -ConnectionString parameter in come custom code I am inserting into the DbMigration.Up() method.  Is there a reference to this that is available there?

> PM> Update-Database -Script -ConnectionString
> "Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydatabase"

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString only give me the default connection string in the base web.config file.  I use transforms on that file to deploy the app, but these transforms aren't available when I'm using Update-Database -Script.  Something like:

> ```
> public partial class MyDbMigration : DbMigration
> {
>     public override void Up()
>     {
>         ...
>
>         var migrationConnectionString = this.ConnectionStringSuppliedToUpdateDatabaseCommand;
>         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(migrationConnectionString))
>         {
>             // some data migration code that must use SqlCommand, not DbMigration.Sql()...
>             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ...", con);  
>         }
>         ...
> ```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I used reflection to look around in the call stack, and dug around the EF6 source code for a while, but wasn't able to find any way to get to the connectionstring that Update-Database uses.  It looks like it lives somewhere in the ProjectCommandBase class, but I can't find any where to get there from Up().